# ORA-00911 Error only with oci_execute

Tags: php, oracle

I've got a problem with the following request:

```
update
    pac_boolean_code
set
    BOO_CODE = 1
where
    PAC_PERSON_ASSOCIATION_ID = '2477764'
and
    DIC_BOOLEAN_CODE_TYP_ID = 'E-CALENDAR';
```

When I execute it in Toad, it works fine. But as soon as I try to use it through PHP using oci_execute, it returns me the "ORA-00911: invalid character" error.

I can't figure what is the problem as all fields are correct and it works when I use it directly in Toad.

If I remove the second where clause (DIC_BOOLEAN_CODE_TYP_ID), it also works !

Any idea to help me ?

Comment: and what type is the DIC_BOOLEAN_CODE_TYP_ID?

Comment: Show table structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon character from the end of your statement, as documented on the [`oci_parse` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php):

> SQL statements *should not* end with a semi-colon (";"). PL/SQL statements *should* end with a semi-colon (";").

Comment: I've tried and it wasn't working; but i've made some changes in the request since so I'll try again as soon as I can reconnect. I'll keep you in touch